# JavaScript preventDefault is delayed/not working when app is deployed on a network

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, preventdefault

I have an application with custom context menus that are displayed on right-click. When that happens, I don't want default windows menu to appear. I use the following code to accomplish that:

```
            // right click
if (e.which == 3) {
    let menuVisible = false;
    const toggleMenu = command => {
        menu.style.display = command === "show" ? "block" : "none";
        menuVisible = !menuVisible;
    };
    const setPosition = ({ top, left }) => {
        menu.style.left = `${left}px`;
        menu.style.top = `${top}px`;
        toggleMenu("show");
    };
    const origin = {
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
    };
    setPosition(origin);
    // toggle right clicked menu visibility
    window.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (menuVisible) toggleMenu("hide");
    });
    // Set up an event handler for the document right click
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (event) {
        // Only do something when the element that was actually right-clicked
        if (event.target.classList.contains("menu")) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
```

When app is running on localhost everything works as expected.
However, when application is deployed on a network server and then accessed from any clients on the network the default menu appears first and then custom menu displayed behind it. There are no any errors.
Any advise on how to fix that will be greatly appreciated.

**Update: It seems that if right mouse button is hold not just clicked the behavior is as expected.**

Comment: Are you sure the code is running?

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client, not the server. It should execute the same no matter where the code was downloaded from.

Comment: Check your console for errors.

Comment: @Barmar. I will fix the wording in the post. What happens when app rans on localhost it works fine. When it deployed on a network accessing it from clients causes the issue

Comment: Is this an inline script in an html file, or is it loaded from an external js file?

Comment: @Teemu. Loaded from external .js

Comment: @Teemu. It is. The file has other functions that work. This one works as but it looks like it's delayed.

Comment: 1. Run the event setting code in console and check. If works then, 2. Clear browser cache for webpage by hitting `Ctrl + F5` and check.

Comment: Did you verify the script is downloaded? Or is it a 404?

Comment: @epascarello There is no issues with scripts. I just noticed that if  right mouse button is hold not just clicked the behavior is as expected.

Comment: @goryef, what browser are you using when testing? Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus. Chrome. The rest of the code is irrelevant to this issues. It works  as expected

Comment: @goryef, does the native contextmenu show up for you in this demo as well? https://jsfiddle.net/o5v7bhgx/

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus. When right click on test button-NO. Everywhere else - YES.

Comment: @goryef, so the `event.preventDefault()` works as expected when isolated. There must be something else going on in your code that causes the issue then.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus. Possibly. But I don't experience this issue when app deployed on localhost, only when on network server. Also it seems to work on network if button is hold not just clicked.

Comment: Any other events registered on menu class, which has some delayed execution? If so, can you try keeping this contextmenu event to be first to register on menu class items.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus. The rest of the code is to display custom context menus. Which are displayed behind default ones when app deployed on a network

Comment: @goryef, can you temporarily remove the other event handlers - but keep the `preventDefault` one - and then test your app again when deployed? This would at least rule out any other problems with the code.

Comment: @Wazeed. Nothing

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus. This is only event listener i have

Comment: @goryef, I meant the remaining code that shows the custom context menus you mentioned. Do you use script elements with `async` or `defer` attributes?

Comment: @goryef Does the issue persist when you "inline" your scripts?

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus. I posted entire code section which responsible for displaying custom context menus.

Comment: I don't know, how this would be related to the host of the page. Anyway, a right click triggers also a click event, you might have a race condition with the attached click event. It doesn't explain why `e.preventDefault()` wouldn't work, though.

Comment: @goryef, It looks as if you register the click- and contextmenu-eventhandlers **within** another event handler. Can't you move these out of the event-handler callback? Otherwise these would be registered again and again on each click which also explains why the native menu shows up at first. You need to register these only **once**.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus. I will look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to do something like this:

```js
let menuVisible = false;

const toggleMenu = command => {
  menu.style.display = command === "show" ? "block" : "none";
  menuVisible = !menuVisible;
};

const setPosition = ({ top, left }) => {
  menu.style.left = `${left}px`;
  menu.style.top = `${top}px`;
};

// Set up an event handler for the document right click
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("menu")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPosition({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
    toggleMenu("show");
  }
});

// Hide menu
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("menu-item")) {
    alert("menu item was clicked");
  }
  toggleMenu("hide"); 
});
```

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu" style="display:none;">
  <li class="menu-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<button class="menu">toggle menu on right click</button>
```